# Generate Signed Bundle/APK option is missing in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I've just set up a new development machine for a Flutter project and need to deploy an APK to tester on the Play Store.

Coming from iOS, I'm not familiar deploying to the Play Store, but in my research I found that I need to create a key store using options found in `Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK` in Android Studio. I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox 3.1. This option `Generate Signed Bundle/APK` does not exist under the Build menu or anywhere else that I can find.

The Flutter and Android SDKs are installed and paths are set. I can compile and run locally as well as build an APK or AppBundle but I cannot generate the necessary keys for Play Store submission.

[image]

Did I miss a setup step in the Android Studio installation? Since this is the latest version of Android Studio, did this option get moved or replaced by something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try open project with android icon. and then generate signed bundle apk will be showing on the build bar

[image]

[image]

Comment: 'Try open project with android icon. ' - how to do that ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed File -> Open... -> Select the 'android' folder in your Flutter project.

Answer (score 9):

Update 2023-07, Flutter Users.

If you are using Flutter, try to open your Android app, under Android Studio, using specific Flutter menu.
You can find here:
move your mouse over
"android [_android]"
push right button mouse,
you will see menu, where the last one option will be Flutter, here you can find:
"Open Android module in Android Studio"

The new window will open and you have to wait to Gradle sync will end.

Now you can find menu to Build signed app, in this new windows menu.

Please see the attached screenshot:

[image: Location of the "Open Android module in Android Studio" option in Android Studio]

Comment: I'm trying to open it but this particular screen I want to open closes immediately. As if it is crashing.

Comment: I have Flutter menu option disabled.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use command line to generate signed apk in flutter.
Since it is a flutter project the option is not available in android studio.

Use this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) to generate signed apk